# Symfony 3.3 Doctrine Fixtures Load skipping SQL views

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, view

I'm trying to use SQL views with Doctrine.

Everything works fine so far, but I have a problem when running a basic fixtures load (with no options). I get the following error messages.

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM gp_items':

SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]View or function 'gp_items' is not updatable
because the modification affects multiple base tables.


[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]View or function 'gp_items' is not updatable
because the modification affects multiple base tables.


[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]View or function 'gp_items' is not updatable
because the modification affects multiple base tables.
```

I looked at the code that loads the fixtures from the bundle ("doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3") and I think I have to alter something to the ORMPurger (Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger) but I'm not sure how to go about that.

So I would like to know how to override a function in that specific class.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

So I decided to fork the DoctrineFixturesBundle and use my own version of it in my project.

https://github.com/jbonnier/DoctrineFixturesBundle

In order for composer to use it, I modified my composer.json file adding the following code before the last closing bracket.

```
,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/jbonnier/DoctrineFixturesBundle"
        }
    ]
```

I also change my require-dev statement to use my personnal branch.

```
 "require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-jbonnier",
   ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Additional explanation.

I'm *currently* working with version v2.4.1 of the bundle.

Here's the change I made to it.

**File : Command/LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php**

Changed line 113

from

```
$purger = new ORMPurger($em);
```

to

```
$purger = new ORMPurger($em, $this->listViews($input->getOption('em')));
```

Add function to class after line 136

```
/**
 * Return an array with all views names in the database. 
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function listViews($entityManager)
{
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager($entityManager);
    $conn = $em->getConnection();
    $sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();

    $views = $sm->listViews();
    $rst = array();

    foreach ($views as $view)
    {
        array_push($rst, $view->getName());
    }

    return $rst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was lazy so I did the workaround to load our fixtures this way.
I you find a clean solution I'm interested

```
bin/console -e=test doctrine:database:drop --if-exists --force
bin/console -e=test doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists --no-interaction
bin/console -e=test doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
bin/console -e=test doctrine:fixtures:load --append --no-interaction
```